# set virtual host on Apache2.2 and PHP 5.3

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2

I want to set my Virtual host on Apache 2.2.

So, I can access my site using my IP address and Port number.

Like http://192.168.101.111:429 for one site, http://192.168.101.111:420 for other site and so on.

My machine OS in Windows 7.

I have tried below in my httpd.conf file.

```
Listen 192.168.101.83:82
#chaffoteaux

<Directory "Path to project folder">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<VirtualHost 192.168.101.83:82>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.html.var
    DocumentRoot "Path to project folder"
    #ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/Zara.log
    #ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    #CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Can you please suggest any thing missing in my configuration.

Thanks in advance

Avinash

Answer (score 2):

You will need to specify the different ports you want apache to listen on.

You also need the

```
NameVirtualHost
```

Directive specified for each IP:port combination you want to use.

Then setup your VirtualHost definitions.

Have a look at [these examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#port) for more info.

**edit**

Put your <Directory> block inside your <VirtualHost> block

Add the lines

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

within your directory block

If you want you can change these settings globally within httpd.conf, rather than have to specify them on a per-virtual-host basis.

Comment: Getting this error:

client denied by server configuration

Comment: see my edit above.